# How to vertically align text within TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-linearlayout, textview

I am trying to get some text vertically aligned within a TextView, but for some reason it just sticks to the top edge of such TextView.

Trust me, I've read several questions here on Stack Overflow regarding the same, or similar, questions and tried applying the provided solutions, but nothing seems to make a change.

For instance, what I thought would solve the issue right away was to add the attribute `android:gravity="center_vertical|left"`, but that didn't help either.

This user's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724144/can%C2%B4t-center-textview%C2%B4s-text-vertically) describes almost exactly my issue, except that his TextView is inside a RelativeLayout which in turn is inside a ScrollView, which I don't (and don't need or want to) use. And the images he provided are also perfectly applicable to what I'm trying to [describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppAdz.png) and [achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7CNT.png).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/account_server_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/account_server_icon"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="left" />    

    <TextView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/tv_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try layout_gravity instead of gravity on yout textview?

Comment: I hadn't tried it before your answer. It does solve the problem, as well as @Tanis.7x answer does. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reference to choose which answer is "more correct" between the ones both of you provided? 
I could accept either one, but I don't want to be unffair, as both solved my problem.

Comment: upvote both and simply choose one to close your question... preferably that resolves directly your kind of problem.

Comment: 1) Both answers resolve directly my problem. I applied both independently and they both work. 2) I can't upvote answers. I don't have 15 rep (btw, how do I get rep?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `TextView`'s height is set to `wrap_content`. This means that the size of the text's container will be the same as the height of the text, thus there really is nowhere within the view to center the content (it is effectively already centered vertically).

If the `LinearLayout` that you posted *only* contains the `ImageView` and the `TextView`, then you can simple change the height to `match_parent` and it should work fine.

If the `LinearLayout` contains other `View`s, you might want to consider using a `RelativeLayout` and setting the `TextView` to align with both the top and bottom of the image.

Comment: Oh boy! That did the trick. I'm still new to developing in Android, so it wasn't as clear to me as it obviously was to you. Thank you, @Tanis.7x

Answer (score 1):

as your achievement suggest, you only need to change your  `gravity` to `layout_gravity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/account_server_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/account_server_icon"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:gravity="left" />    

    <TextView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/tv_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set gravity then you set text alignment to gravity

```
<TextView
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/tv_account"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
 />
```